# Model Class returns null

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[model class is returning null, data is coming from Firebase database but upon getting imageUrl its giving null.

Actually, I am trying to get images urls from database which are previously saved.

```
    firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();   

    databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getInstance().
    getReference("Catagories");
    mupload=new ArrayList<>();`


     databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Upload upload=post.getValue(Upload.class);
            mupload.add(upload);
                        }
            customQuoteAdapter=new CustomQuoteAdapter( Images.this,     

          mupload);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(customQuoteAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),   
  "ERROR"+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: We have no way to know what `databaseReference` is initialized to, while it is likely to point to the cause of the problem. Please update your question to include the minimum **standalone** code that is needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen its refering to Catagories

Comment: Don't tell us what it is, but show the code. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen have a look now. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `bussiness` (sic) level in your JSON, that you're not handling in your code. The simplest way to fix this is to attach your listener to that `bussiness` node:

```
databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Catagories/Bussiness");
mupload=new ArrayList<>();`


 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot post : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Upload upload=post.getValue(Upload.class);
            mupload.add(upload);
        }
        customQuoteAdapter=new CustomQuoteAdapter( Images.this, mupload);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customQuoteAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR"+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

If you want to get all URLS for all nodes under `Categories`, you'll need to add a loop inside `onDataChange`. Something like:

```
databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Catagories");
mupload=new ArrayList<>();`


 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot categorySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot linkSnapshot : categorySnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload=linkSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                mupload.add(upload);
            }
        }
        customQuoteAdapter=new CustomQuoteAdapter( Images.this, mupload);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customQuoteAdapter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR"+databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: i want to get all image urls under catagories. like under bussiness, programming etc. so, how to do that.

Comment: I added an example for that to my answer.

Comment: after following your example, Model class is still returning null for imageUrl

Comment: its returning url but not displaying in the imageview

Comment: Please have a look at my custom adapter class

Comment: Since you can now get the URLs from the database, it sounds to me like you have a new problem: how to display the image from a valid URL inside a view.  I'd post a new question for that, and revert this one to its previous state so that it's more helpful to others in the future. For your new question: try to isolate the problem in as little code as possible, to make it both more likely that you find the problem yourself, and easier for others to help. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more on this.

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for the edit. The typo was actually intentional. since that how OP misspelled it. I reverted to the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be?

```
public String getImageUrl() {
    return this.imageUrl;
}
```

Comment: still same. returning null.